# Can you or can't you use a property from a config file when using Spring @Condition?

Tags: spring

I have read pretty much everything I can find on StackOverflow and other sites and I don't see a definitive answer anywhere.

I have a class that implements @Condition that I use in a @Configuration file to conditionally load some beans. I am doing something like this:

```
public class MyCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metdata) {
        String property = context.getEnvironment().getProperty("some.prop.from.file");
        boolean enable = Boolean.parseBoolean(property);
        return enable;
    }
```

}

When debugging I see that getting the property from the environment always returns null, even though the property is injected in other beans using @Value.

So my question can you or can't you attempt to get a property value from a file within a @Condition class? Can you only get System properties? I would think that this is a common use case that I would think Spring could handle.

Comment: we can definitely get property. check out this example http://javapapers.com/spring/spring-conditional-annotation/

Comment: In this example you have to add the property as a "VM argument" in Eclipse. I want to be able to read it from a property file. It appears that the properties are not getting loaded in my Spring app until after the Condition class has already been ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add the property to application.properties and not the other property files that are loaded during startup.